# How do you copy text from Firefox in Windows to bash shell in Unix?

Tags: windows, bash, unix, copy-paste

I have a long URL on a web page in Windows that I need to copy into bash shell in Unix. Is there a way to do this without retyping the URL?

Comment: Yeah, stick in a USB hard drive in a mouse to work as a clipboard, file a patent and use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you connect to unix using putty, copy the text from the browser, then right click on the putty window to paste.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Synergy](http://synergy2.sourceforge.net/) to share your clipboard between the two machines.

Comment: I love synergy... Don't know how I'd get through the day without it.

Answer (score 1):

I routinely run x2vnc from a Linux box, and have a VNC server (RealVNC) running on a Windows box. This lets me share one mouse and keyboard across the two machines, and the clipboard is also shared across the machines.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to right clicking in the putty window, you can also paste by pressing Shift+Insert in the putty window.

(I learned this from the FAQ at the putty website)

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Windows, and you have a Putty session into your unix box, then you can copy the URL to the clipboard in Windows, and then right-click in the putty window. This will do a paste. You could do that paste into a vi session and save the url.

Another option is using the `write` command. That is, open a terminal on the unix box, and then use Putty to SSH into that same box. do a `write tonge` (assuming 'tonge' is your user name), paste the URL, and press enter. The recipient (that is, you, with a bash terminal open) will receive that URL.